# appsettings load json dynamically from folder

Tags: c#, json, configuration, .net-6.0, appsettings

Hello my team manages a multitenant application and we need to have as much downtime possible when we add a new tenant access information (token and connection string).

They fear that in case of error modifying connections.json file all tenants will have their configuration inaccessible. so we thought to create a json for each tenant and only define the folder. we could potentially have hundreds of files.

in Program class is it possible to define a folder and dynamically load all json files in that folder, instead of defining json names?

Comment: Yes, you can, just enumerate *.json files from that folder and for each of them call `ConfigurationBuilder.AddJson(json)`. So, that's straightforward way to do this.

Comment: but can i do it in a way that it can load newly added jsons, without restarting the application?